# How can I send data to phpmyadmin on raspberry pi from another computer?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, raspberry-pi3

What I want to do? Access the database on one computer from another computer and send or receive data there. But i have error. "The error code: 2002".

I can send sensor data to phpmyadmin on raspberry pi. I want to receive this data into index.php on another computer.

I researched a lot but I couldn't reach the result...How should I do?

Comment: phpMyAdmin is a graphical interface for administrators to manage a MySQL or MariaDB installation, it isn't an API for your other computer to access. You'll have to find some other solution, perhaps write your own API or expose MySQL's port 3306 to the other machine to access directly across the network.

Comment: Do you find solution for this?